# How to compare date and execute the below code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

If Purchase Date is after 31/Mar/xxxx it should not calculate **elap_yend, rem_days, depre_cur, cur_wdv**.

Also I have to calculate GST with some options that is if **SGST and CGST** are chosen, I should **not calculate IGST** else if **IGST selected** or marked it **should not calculate SGST and CGST**.

How can I resolve this?

```
<body>

<div class="form-group mx-auto" >

<div class="form-row " >
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Purchase Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="pur_date" name="pur_date" onchange="cal()" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>End Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end_date" name="end_date" onchange="cal()"required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row " >
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Product Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_price" name="product_price" placeholder="Enter Amount"  required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>IGST</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="igst" name="igst"  required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>SGST</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sgst" name="sgst"   required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>CGST</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cgst" name="cgst"  required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Total Amount</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Enter Total" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Depre Amount</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dep_amount" id="dep_amount" required>
    </div>   
  </div>  
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Life in Days</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="life_days" id="life_days" placeholder="Enter Total life" required>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Elapsed Days(31/03)</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="elap_yend" id="elap_yend" onchange="cal()" readonly/>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Remaining Days</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rem_days" id="rem_days" placeholder="Enter Product No" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Current Depreciation</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="depre_cur" name="depre_cur" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>W.D.V(Curr)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cur_wdv" name="cur_wdv" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-row " >
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Next Year Starting</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="nextyearstart_date" name="pur_date" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Next Year End Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="nextyearend_date" name="nextyearend_date" >
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row " >
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Depreciation 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="depre_next" name="depre_next"  required/>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>W.D.V(Next)</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="next_wdv" id="next_wdv"  /> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Accum Depreciation</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_depre" name="acc_depre" placeholder="Enter Location" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Sale Amount</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sale_amount" name="sale_amount" placeholder="Enter sale amount" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Profit/Loss</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pro_los" name="pro_los" placeholder="Enter Product Desc" required/>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetDays(){
                var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("end_date").value);
                 var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("pur_date").value);
                //var pickdt = new Date();
                return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
        }

        function cal(){
        if(document.getElementById("end_date")){
            document.getElementById("elap_yend").value=GetDays();
        }  
    }

    $(product_price).ready(function(){

    var $nextyearstart_date =  $( "#nextyearstart_date" );
    var $nextyearend_date =  $( "#nextyearend_date" );

    $nextyearstart_date.datepicker();
    $nextyearend_date.datepicker({
        onClose: function() {
        var product_price;
        var igst;
        var cgst;
        var sgst;

        product_price = parseFloat($('#product_price').val());

        life_days = parseFloat($('#life_days').val());

        elap_yend = parseFloat($('#elap_yend').val());

        dep_amount = parseFloat($('#dep_amount').val());

        depre_cur = parseFloat($('#depre_cur').val());

        igst = parseFloat($('#igst').val());

        cgst = parseFloat($('#cgst').val());

        sgst = parseFloat($('#sgst').val());

        var igst = product_price * 0.09;
        $('#igst').val(igst.toFixed(2));

        var cgst = product_price * 0.09;
        $('#cgst').val(cgst.toFixed(2));

        var sgst = product_price * 0;
        $('#sgst').val(sgst.toFixed(2));

        var total = product_price + igst + cgst + sgst;
        $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));

        var dep_amount = product_price + (.5 * (igst + cgst + sgst));
        $('#dep_amount').val(dep_amount.toFixed(2));

        var rem_days = life_days - elap_yend;
        $('#rem_days').val(rem_days.toFixed(2));

        var depre_cur = (dep_amount/life_days) * elap_yend;    //life_days - elap_yend;
        $('#depre_cur').val(depre_cur.toFixed(2));

        var cur_wdv = dep_amount - depre_cur;    //life_days - elap_yend;
        $('#cur_wdv').val(cur_wdv.toFixed(2));
            var fromDate = $nextyearstart_date.datepicker('getDate');
            var toDate = $nextyearend_date.datepicker('getDate');

            var diff = new Date(toDate - fromDate);

            var Ddays = diff/1000/60/60/24;

            var depre_next = Ddays * (dep_amount/life_days);

        $('#depre_next').val(depre_next.toFixed(2));

        var next_wdv = cur_wdv - depre_next;
        $('#next_wdv').val(next_wdv.toFixed(2));

        var acc_depre = depre_cur + depre_next;
        $('#acc_depre').val(acc_depre.toFixed(2));

        var pro_los = depre_cur + depre_next;
        $('#pro_los').val(pro_los.toFixed(2));
           // alert(depre_next);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Could you structure your question better please. Newlines and interpunction would greatly improve readability.

Comment: I want to calculate CGST,SGST,IGST (with some percentage ex: 9%)but the thing is if am selecting a check box it should calculate CST & SGST else it should calculate IGST. Thanks for your response

Comment: omg. Noone is giving answer for GST calculation. Please help me

Comment: You seem impatient. People devote their time to solve questions here. I'm surprised that there is even an answer given, with the amount of code in your question.

A lot of people speak different languages en come from different cultures. Your code has no comments what so ever. So provide the necessary information about abbreviations and other nomenclature to us if you want a more useful answer.

Comment: Sorry for that but i got a solution. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date comparisons in JavaScript can be tricky. Sometimes it's best to use a third party date library, like MomentJS or Luxon.

The basics of what you want to do are fairly basic though. Create the date you want as your baseline, then your test date, and do simple comparison.

```
const cutoffDate = new Date('March 31, 2018 23:59:59');
const testDate = new Date(); // now

if (testDate >= cutoffDate) {
  // do this calculation
} else {
  // ok, do this calculation
}
```

Thing that always trip people up is timezones (which is why the third party libraries are good). When using the JS `Date` object, remember that it will use the timezone of the browser, so the date object created will be different between a user at a system in New York vs a user at a system in Shanghai.

Comment: Help me for this I want to calculate CGST,SGST,IGST (with some percentage ex: 9%)but the thing is if am selecting a check box it should calculate CST & SGST else it should calculate IGST. Thanks for your response

Comment: @MONEYMSN I volunteered my time to answer your question, on how to test dates to choose your process path. I have done what I can to give you the tools you need to succeed on your own. It is now up to you to choose how you proceed with your application, I cannot do this for you. If you have a different question, write that up in a new question.

Comment: am ok with dates and i have done that but i need regarding that GST calculation. Please help me out i couldnot crack this. Thanks in advance